# How can I fix this cycle in order to iterate several times?

Tags: code-review, broken-code

I have been working on a code whose only purpose is to get the mean value over four numbers. And I managed to do one cycle, however after trying to repeat this process until a certain condition is accomplished. My program entered a loop, and I have no idea how to fix it or how should I have done it. I would appreciate your comments about it in order to help me fix this code.

**This is the dimension of the table that I used, but in reality it has some values.

```
n=2 or 4 or 6 or ...
m=n+2
DatPol = Table[{0, 0, 0}, {i, 4*n}, {j, m}]
ϕ = Pi/2;
θ = -Pi/2;
Hi = ϕ/n;
k = 1;
a = 4;
r = 1;
P1[θ_] := (a - r*Abs[Cos[θ]])/(n*Abs[Cos[θ]]);
P2[θ_] := (a - r*Abs[Sin[θ]])/(n*Abs[Sin[θ]]);
l1[θ_, f_] := r + f*P1[θ];
l2[θ_, f_] := r + f*P2[θ]
```

### This is only one cycle (that works)

```
θ = -Pi/2;
k = 1;
p = 2;

Iteration = 
  Reap[ While[θ < 3*Pi/2 , 
    Sow[ If[(θ == -Pi/2  || θ == (3*Pi/2 - Hi)), 
      DatPol = 
       ReplacePart[
         DatPol, {k, p, 
           3} ->  (Part[DatPol, k, p + 1, 3] + 
             Part[DatPol, k, p - 1, 3] + 
             Part[DatPol, k + (4*n - 1)*(-1)^(k + 1), p, 3] + 
             Part[DatPol, k + (-1)^(k + 1), p, 3])/4 ]   || (-Pi/
           2 < θ < (3*Pi/2 - Hi)) , 
      DatPol = 
       ReplacePart[
        DatPol, {k, p, 
          3} ->  (Part[DatPol, k, p + 1, 3] + 
            Part[DatPol, k, p - 1, 3] + Part[DatPol, k - 1, p, 3] + 
            Part[DatPol, k + 1, p, 3])/4  ] ]]; p = p + 1; 
    If[p == m, θ = θ + Hi, Continue[]]; 
    If[p == m, k = k + 1 , Continue[]]; 
    If[p == m, p = 2, Continue[]]  ]];
```

---

**And this is my attempt for an iteration until a difference between two numbers is greater than 0.01, (but it doesn't work, who knows why)**

---

```
θ = -Pi/2;
k = 1;
p = 2;
V = 1*10^(-2);
Dif = 2

Iteracion = 
 Reap[ While[Dif > V, 
   Sow[ If[(θ == -Pi/2  || θ == (3*Pi/2 - Hi)), 
     DatPol = 
      ReplacePart[
        DatPol, {k, p, 
          3} ->  (Part[DatPol, k, p + 1, 3] + 
            Part[DatPol, k, p - 1, 3] + 
            Part[DatPol, k + (4*n - 1)*(-1)^(k + 1), p, 3] + 
            Part[DatPol, k + (-1)^(k + 1), p, 3])/4 ]   || (-Pi/
          2 < θ < (3*Pi/2 - Hi)) , 
     DatPol = 
      ReplacePart[
       DatPol, {k, p, 
         3} ->  (Part[DatPol, k, p + 1, 3] + 
           Part[DatPol, k, p - 1, 3] + Part[DatPol, k - 1, p, 3] + 
           Part[DatPol, k + 1, p, 3])/4  ] ]]; p = p + 1;
   If[p == m, θ = θ + Hi, Continue[]]; 
   If[p == m, k = k + 1 , Continue[]];
   If[p == m, p = 2, Continue[]]; 
   If[θ == 3*Pi/2, 
    Dif = Abs[Part[DatPol, 2, 2, 3] - Part[DatPol, 2, 3, 3]], 
   Continue[]]; If[θ == 3*Pi/2, Print[N[Dif]], Continue[]];
   If[θ == 3*Pi/2, k = 1, Continue[]]; 
   If[θ == 3*Pi/2, θ = -Pi/2, Continue[]]  ]]
```

Comment: Your `Hi` parameter is undefined. And can you explain in more detail what you're trying to do, and what you're trying to do it to? I'm having a hard time connecting your code to the assertion that its "only purpose is to get the mean value over four numbers". What are you `Sow`ing and `Reap`ing? What is your `While` loop working through?

Comment: The idea is to get the solution to the Laplace equation, given a square with size $axa$ with potential cero, and inside the square a circle of radius r with potential $sen\theta$, so I made up a kind of net in which the columns are radius coordinates and the rows are angles, so the points inside my table are like $(r,\theta,\phi)$, So I am just getting the mean value evaluating around a certain point according with the points around it. And I need to repeat the process in order to get a convergence in the potential (relaxation method).

Comment: I didn't wanted to explained a lot because I just coding a mean value, and trying to iterate several times.

Comment: Or well if you don't understand the iteration part, could you give me an idea on how to iterate the cycle part above?

Comment: Maybe you should look up `Mean` in the documentation...